# Why is Xcode Giving Me These Errors?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-carbon

The error I get is Xcode saying 3 things are un-declared (see below picture)
[alt text http://snapplr.com/snap/ks4h](http://snapplr.com/snap/ks4h)

But in the Header File I have declared them (see below picture)

[alt text http://snapplr.com/snap/htmb](http://snapplr.com/snap/htmb)

Why I am getting these errors when I have declared them.

The Full Code:

Header File.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface HotKeyController : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSButton *cmdHK;
    IBOutlet NSButton *ctrHK;
    IBOutlet NSButton *optHK;
    IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *keyHK;
    IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
    IBOutlet NSWindow *searchWindow;
    IBOutlet NSWindow *entryWindow;
}

@end
```

Implementation File

```
#import "HotKeyController.h"
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>

@implementation HotKeyController

OSStatus MyHotKeyHandler(EventHandlerCallRef nextHandler,EventRef theEvent,void *userData)
{
    EventHotKeyID hkCom;
    GetEventParameter(theEvent,kEventParamDirectObject,typeEventHotKeyID,NULL,sizeof(hkCom),NULL,&hkCom);
    int l = hkCom.id;

    switch (l) {
        case 1: [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];  
            break;
        case 2: [searchWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
            break;
        case 3: [entryWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
            break;  
    }
    return noErr;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    //Register the Hotkeys
    EventHotKeyRef gMyHotKeyRef;
    EventHotKeyID gMyHotKeyID;
    EventTypeSpec eventType;
    eventType.eventClass=kEventClassKeyboard;
    eventType.eventKind=kEventHotKeyPressed;


    InstallApplicationEventHandler(&MyHotKeyHandler,1,&eventType,pl,NULL);

    gMyHotKeyID.signature='htk1';
    gMyHotKeyID.id=1;
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"hotkeyShowMain"]!=-999) {
        RegisterEventHotKey([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"hotkeyShowMain"], [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"hotkeyShowMainModifier"], gMyHotKeyID, GetApplicationEventTarget(), 0, &gMyHotKeyRef);
    }

    gMyHotKeyID.signature='htk2';
    gMyHotKeyID.id=2;
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"hotkeyShowSearch"]!=-999) {
        RegisterEventHotKey([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"hotkeyShowSearch"], [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"hotkeyShowSearchModifier"], gMyHotKeyID, GetApplicationEventTarget(), 0, &gMyHotKeyRef);
    }

    gMyHotKeyID.signature='htk3';
    gMyHotKeyID.id=3;
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"hotkeyShowEntry"]!=-999) {
        RegisterEventHotKey([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"hotkeyShowEntry"], [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"hotkeyShowEntryModifiers"], gMyHotKeyID, GetApplicationEventTarget(), 0, &gMyHotKeyRef);
    }

}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to show more of the file to be sure. Are you properly importing the header file? Have you saved the header file?

Try inserting the explicit self-> references and you might get a more revealing error message.

Also, try preprocessing the implementation file (in the Build menu) and that might reveal why the ivar isn't being found.

Comment: How would you pre process the implementation file? I have also updated the question with the full code.

Comment: The additional context you added is immediately helpful. References to the ivars must be within Objective-C method definitions, because the implicit self parameter is needed to access them.

You obviously can't do that since you are implementing a Carbon callback function. However, if you make the userData parameter a pointer to your HotKeyController, you should be able to access them that way.

Comment: How would I make the userData parameter point to my HotKeyController?

Comment: InstallApplicationEventHandler(&MyHotKeyHandler,1,&eventType,(void *)self,NULL);

Note the 4th parameter. Not sure what the "pl" you're currently passing is.

Then, in the callback you can cast userData to (HotKeyController *) and access its ivars.

Make sure something is keeping the HotKeyController object alive so the callbacks don't get a dangling pointer.

Comment: How would I cast userData to (HotKeyController *) and access its ivars?

Comment: HotKeyController *controller = (HotKeyController *)userData;
controller->window;

This is basic C stuff.

Comment: *sigh*... Put it in MyHotKeyHandler. The first line goes somewhere before the switch statement. Replace any references to 'window' with controller->window, searchWindow with controller->searchWindow, and so forth.

If the compiler complains about direct access of the ivars (not sure if it would in this case), you'll want to make accessor functions and call those instead.

Comment: Thanks but What is the Switch Statement?

Comment: Found out what the Switch Statement was so I put directly before it, but got multiple errors. Pic. http://snapplr.com/sjvw

Comment: Also tried putting it in a different place, but still got errors. Pic. http://snapplr.com/xhr1

Comment: Heh... this is ludicrous, but I'll play along, since I'm amused. You forgot a semicolon after the declaration. That should be obvious.

Answer (score 6):

> The error I get is Xcode saying 3 things are un-declared …
>
> But in the Header File I have declared them …
>
> Why I am getting these errors when I have declared them [in the HotKeyController class].

Because those lines are in a function, not in a method of the HotKeyController class. It doesn't matter where you put the function (inside `@implementation` or not); it's still a function, not a method.

> How would I make the `userData` parameter point to my HotKeyController?

You set that when you create the event handler. In fact, you're already setting it to “`pl`”, whatever that is.

Comment: Ah, I see. The thing is I got the code from a tutorial. In fact "pl" is also un-declared. Do you know what I should change it to?

Comment: You wanted to change it to the HotKeyController, remember?

Comment: No, that's a class name. That would be a syntax error, and you don't want to pass the class anyway. You need to pass the HotKeyController object—the one you're installing the event handler from. (And if you don't know how to do that, you should re-read the Objective-C Programming Language: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/ in particular: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-BAJHDGAC )

Answer (score 0):

NSWindow is not defined in the Foundation framework,
you must import the right headers, ApplicationKit or Cocoa.

Comment: Failing to import the AppKit header would not cause his instance variables to go missing. His problem is that he's trying to access them from a function.